# Fetch rows on one table that doesn't exist on the other

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm having a hard time getting rows on one of the table. Example on the table below, i want to output rows on the table `tbl_loan_master` that has no transaction on `tbl_loanledger` within the current month (June). I have already an existing query which is working that returns last transaction of each borrower within the current month (June) but not on the `tbl_loan_master` table. The column deleted means if the value is equal to 1 it is deleted and 0 if not.

**tbl_borrowers**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | first_name | last_name | deleted  |  date_created |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    Bill    |   Snow    |    0     |  2016/04/08   |
|  2 |    Meg     |   Rib     |    0     |  2016/04/13   |
|  3 |    Yin     |   Ling    |    0     |  2016/05/17   |
|  4 |    Sam     |   Taylor  |    0     |  2016/05/17   |
|  5 |    Bob     |   Canny   |    1     |  2016/05/25   |
|  6 |    Drake   |   Fig     |    0     |  2016/05/28   |
|  7 |    May     |   Mcday   |    0     |  2016/05/28   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**tbl_loan_master**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | borrower_id  |  loan  | date_created |  due_date  |  deleted  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       4      |  300   |   2016/04/28 | 2017/04/28 |     0     |
|  2 |       1      |  100   |   2016/05/05 | 2017/05/05 |     0     |
|  3 |       2      |  500   |   2016/06/08 | 2017/06/08 |     0     |
|  4 |       1      |  200   |   2016/06/13 | 2017/06/13 |     0     |
|  5 |       3      |  150   |   2016/06/15 | 2017/06/15 |     0     |
|  6 |       6      |   50   |   2016/06/16 | 2017/06/16 |     0     |
|  7 |       1      |  100   |   2016/06/20 | 2017/06/20 |     1     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**tbl_loanledger**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | borrower_id  | loanmaster_id | payment | balance| date_created | deleted |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       4      |      1        |    50   |   250  |  2016/05/28  |    0    |
|  2 |       1      |      2        |    20   |    80  |  2016/05/25  |    0    |
|  3 |       1      |      2        |    30   |    50  |  2016/06/01  |    0    |
|  4 |       2      |      3        |   100   |   400  |  2016/06/09  |    0    |
|  5 |       2      |      3        |    50   |   350  |  2016/06/10  |    0    |
|  6 |       1      |      4        |    50   |   200  |  2016/06/16  |    0    |
|  7 |       1      |      7        |    50   |   250  |  2016/06/16  |    1    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Result Set**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| last_name | first_name | balance or loan | due_date   |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    Fig    |    Drake   |       50        | 2017/06/16 |
|    Ling   |    Yin     |       150       | 2017/06/15 |
|    Rib    |    Meg     |       350       | 2017/06/08 |
|    Snow   |    Bill    |       200       | 2017/06/13 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**This is the query**

```
select t.first_name, t.last_name, t1.due_date, coalesce(t.loan_balance, t1.loan) as balance
    from (
        select t1.*, t2.loan_balance, t2.date_created as d, t2.loanmaster_id, t2.id as tid
        from ".tbl_borrowers." t1
        left join ".tbl_loanledger." t2
        on t1.id = t2.borrower_id
        where t1.deleted = 0 ) t
    left join (
        select t3.* 
        from ".tbl_loan_master." t3
        inner join (select max(id) as id from ".tbl_loan_master." group by borrower_id) t4 on t3.id = t4.id
            ) t1 on t.id = t1.borrower_id
    where month(t.d) = month(now())
    and t.tid in (select max(id) from ".tbl_loanledger." group by borrower_id)
    or t.d is null
    order by t.last_name
```

I'm having a hard time on this one, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please help me on this one. . .

Comment: So ling,taylor and fig should be in result set. If there are no transactions in ledger balance should come from tbl_loan_master. If there is a transaction in ledger that is before june and that transaction creation date > tbl_master.date_created  balance should come from last ledger entry for borrower_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
CREATE table tbl_borrowers (id int,first_name varchar(10), last_name varchar(10), deleted  int,  date_created date);
truncate table  tbl_borrowers;
insert into  tbl_borrowers values
(  1 ,    'Bill'    ,   'Snow'   ,     0     ,  '2016/04/08'),   
(  2 ,    'Meg'     ,   'Rib'    ,     0     ,  '2016/04/13'),  
(  3 ,    'Yin'     ,   'Ling'   ,     0     ,  '2016/05/17'),   
(  4 ,    'Sam'     ,   'Taylor' ,     0     ,  '2016/05/17'),   
(  5 ,    'Bob'     ,   'Canny'  ,     1     ,  '2016/05/25'),   
(  6 ,    'Drake'   ,   'Fig'    ,     0     ,  '2016/05/28'),   
(  7 ,    'May'     ,   'Mcday'  ,     0     ,  '2016/05/28')  ; 
drop table tbl_loan_master;
create table tbl_loan_master(id int,borrower_id int,loan int,date_created date,due_date date,deleted int);
truncate table tbl_loan_master;
insert into tbl_loan_master values
(  1 ,       4      ,  300   ,   '2016/04/28' , '2017/04/28' ,     0    ),
(  2 ,       1      ,  100   ,   '2016/05/05' , '2017/05/05' ,     0    ), 
(  3 ,       2      ,  500   ,   '2016/06/08' , '2017/06/08' ,     0    ), 
(  4 ,       1      ,  200   ,   '2016/06/13' , '2017/06/13' ,     0    ), 
(  5 ,       3      ,  150   ,   '2016/06/15' , '2017/06/15' ,     0    ), 
(  6 ,       6      ,   50   ,   '2016/06/16' , '2017/06/16' ,     0    ), 
(  7 ,       1      ,  100   ,   '2016/06/20' , '2017/06/20' ,     1    ) ;

create table tbl_loanledger(id int,borrower_id int,loanmaster_id int,payment int,balance int,date_created date,deleted int);
truncate table tbl_loanledger;
insert into tbl_loanledger values
(  1 ,       4      ,      1        ,    50   ,   250  ,  '2016/05/28'  ,    0   ),
(  2 ,       1      ,      2        ,    20   ,    80  ,  '2016/05/25'  ,    0   ), 
(  3 ,       1      ,      2        ,    30   ,    50  ,  '2016/06/01'  ,    0   ), 
(  4 ,       2      ,      3        ,   100   ,   400  ,  '2016/06/09'  ,    0   ), 
(  5 ,       2      ,      3        ,    50   ,   350  ,  '2016/06/10'  ,    0   ), 
(  6 ,       1      ,      4        ,    50   ,   200  ,  '2016/06/16'  ,    0   ), 
(  7 ,       1      ,      7        ,    50   ,   250  ,  '2016/06/16'  ,    1   ) ;
*/
select  t.last_name,t.first_name,t.borrower_id,
            case    
                when t.lldatecreated is null then t.loan
                else t.balance
                end as 'Loan or Balance'
                ,t.lmdatecreated
                ,t.due_date
                ,t.lldatecreated
from    
(
select  b.last_name,b.first_name,lm.borrower_id,lm.loan ,lm.date_created as lmdatecreated, lm.due_date,s.balance,s.lldatecreated
from    tbl_loan_master lm
join        tbl_borrowers b on b.id = lm.borrower_id 
left outer join
(
select  ll.borrower_id ,ll.date_created as lldatecreated,ll.balance
from    tbl_loanledger ll 
where       ll.id = (
                        select      max(ll1.id) 
                        from    tbl_loanledger ll1
                        where       ll1.borrower_id = ll.borrower_id
                        and ll1.deleted <> 1
                        #and year(ll1.date_created) * 12 + month(ll1.date_created) = year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) 
                        )
) s on lm.borrower_id = s.borrower_id
where       lm.id = (
                        select      max(lml.id) 
                        from    tbl_loan_master lml
                        where       lml.borrower_id = lm.borrower_id
                        and deleted <> 1
                        )
              and b.deleted <> 1
) t
where       t.lldatecreated is null or 
            (
            year(t.lldatecreated) * 12 + month(t.lldatecreated) < year(now()) * 12 + month(now())
            and  t.lldatecreated >= t.lmdatecreated
            )
;
```